# How to set an if statment for three values x y and z

Tags: python, user-interface, if-statement, tkinter

I am trying to make a test and I want to print well done if the person gets the answers in the right order. I dont know how to make sure the if statement works for every value.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

app = Tk()
# Message Window

def messagePop():
    get_data()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Results', '100% Very Good')

# Background colour

app.configure(bg='cornflower blue')

COLORS  =['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
    'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond', 'bisque', 'peach puff',
    'navajo white', 'lemon chiffon', 'mint cream', 'azure', 'alice blue', 'lavender',
    'lavender blush', 'misty rose', 'dark slate gray', 'dim gray', 'slate gray',
    'light slate gray', 'gray', 'light grey', 'midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue',
    'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue',  'blue',
    'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue', 'sky blue', 'light sky blue', 'steel blue', 'light steel blue',
    'light blue', 'powder blue', 'pale turquoise', 'dark turquoise', 'medium turquoise', 'turquoise',
    'cyan', 'light cyan', 'cadet blue', 'medium aquamarine', 'aquamarine', 'dark green', 'dark olive green',
    'dark sea green', 'sea green', 'medium sea green', 'light sea green', 'pale green', 'spring green',
    'lawn green', 'medium spring green', 'green yellow', 'lime green', 'yellow green',
    'forest green', 'olive drab', 'dark khaki', 'khaki', 'pale goldenrod', 'light goldenrod yellow',
    'light yellow', 'yellow', 'gold', 'light goldenrod', 'goldenrod', 'dark goldenrod', 'rosy brown',
    'indian red', 'saddle brown', 'sandy brown',
    'dark salmon', 'salmon', 'light salmon', 'orange', 'dark orange',
    'coral', 'light coral', 'tomato', 'orange red', 'red', 'hot pink', 'deep pink', 'pink', 'light pink',
    'pale violet red', 'maroon', 'medium violet red', 'violet red',
    'medium orchid', 'dark orchid', 'dark violet', 'blue violet', 'purple', 'medium purple',
    'thistle', 'snow2', 'snow3',
    'snow4', 'seashell2', 'seashell3', 'seashell4', 'AntiqueWhite1', 'AntiqueWhite2',
    'AntiqueWhite3', 'AntiqueWhite4', 'bisque2', 'bisque3', 'bisque4', 'PeachPuff2',
    'PeachPuff3', 'PeachPuff4', 'NavajoWhite2', 'NavajoWhite3', 'NavajoWhite4',
    'LemonChiffon2', 'LemonChiffon3', 'LemonChiffon4', 'cornsilk2', 'cornsilk3',
    'cornsilk4', 'ivory2', 'ivory3', 'ivory4', 'honeydew2', 'honeydew3', 'honeydew4',
    'LavenderBlush2', 'LavenderBlush3', 'LavenderBlush4', 'MistyRose2', 'MistyRose3',
    'MistyRose4', 'azure2', 'azure3', 'azure4', 'SlateBlue1', 'SlateBlue2', 'SlateBlue3',
    'SlateBlue4', 'RoyalBlue1', 'RoyalBlue2', 'RoyalBlue3', 'RoyalBlue4', 'blue2', 'blue4',
    'DodgerBlue2', 'DodgerBlue3', 'DodgerBlue4', 'SteelBlue1', 'SteelBlue2',
    'SteelBlue3', 'SteelBlue4', 'DeepSkyBlue2', 'DeepSkyBlue3', 'DeepSkyBlue4',
    'SkyBlue1', 'SkyBlue2', 'SkyBlue3', 'SkyBlue4', 'LightSkyBlue1', 'LightSkyBlue2',
    'LightSkyBlue3', 'LightSkyBlue4', 'SlateGray1', 'SlateGray2', 'SlateGray3',
    'SlateGray4', 'LightSteelBlue1', 'LightSteelBlue2', 'LightSteelBlue3',
    'LightSteelBlue4', 'LightBlue1', 'LightBlue2', 'LightBlue3', 'LightBlue4',
    'LightCyan2', 'LightCyan3', 'LightCyan4', 'PaleTurquoise1', 'PaleTurquoise2',
    'PaleTurquoise3', 'PaleTurquoise4', 'CadetBlue1', 'CadetBlue2', 'CadetBlue3',
    'CadetBlue4', 'turquoise1', 'turquoise2', 'turquoise3', 'turquoise4', 'cyan2', 'cyan3',
    'cyan4', 'DarkSlateGray1', 'DarkSlateGray2', 'DarkSlateGray3', 'DarkSlateGray4',
    'aquamarine2', 'aquamarine4', 'DarkSeaGreen1', 'DarkSeaGreen2', 'DarkSeaGreen3',
    'DarkSeaGreen4', 'SeaGreen1', 'SeaGreen2', 'SeaGreen3', 'PaleGreen1', 'PaleGreen2',
    'PaleGreen3', 'PaleGreen4', 'SpringGreen2', 'SpringGreen3', 'SpringGreen4',
    'green2', 'green3', 'green4', 'chartreuse2', 'chartreuse3', 'chartreuse4',
    'OliveDrab1', 'OliveDrab2', 'OliveDrab4', 'DarkOliveGreen1', 'DarkOliveGreen2',
    'DarkOliveGreen3', 'DarkOliveGreen4', 'khaki1', 'khaki2', 'khaki3', 'khaki4',
    'LightGoldenrod1', 'LightGoldenrod2', 'LightGoldenrod3', 'LightGoldenrod4',
    'LightYellow2', 'LightYellow3', 'LightYellow4', 'yellow2', 'yellow3', 'yellow4',
    'gold2', 'gold3', 'gold4', 'goldenrod1', 'goldenrod2', 'goldenrod3', 'goldenrod4',
    'DarkGoldenrod1', 'DarkGoldenrod2', 'DarkGoldenrod3', 'DarkGoldenrod4',
    'RosyBrown1', 'RosyBrown2', 'RosyBrown3', 'RosyBrown4', 'IndianRed1', 'IndianRed2',
    'IndianRed3', 'IndianRed4', 'sienna1', 'sienna2', 'sienna3', 'sienna4', 'burlywood1',
    'burlywood2', 'burlywood3', 'burlywood4', 'wheat1', 'wheat2', 'wheat3', 'wheat4', 'tan1',
    'tan2', 'tan4', 'chocolate1', 'chocolate2', 'chocolate3', 'firebrick1', 'firebrick2',
    'firebrick3', 'firebrick4', 'brown1', 'brown2', 'brown3', 'brown4', 'salmon1', 'salmon2',
    'salmon3', 'salmon4', 'LightSalmon2', 'LightSalmon3', 'LightSalmon4', 'orange2',
    'orange3', 'orange4', 'DarkOrange1', 'DarkOrange2', 'DarkOrange3', 'DarkOrange4',
    'coral1', 'coral2', 'coral3', 'coral4', 'tomato2', 'tomato3', 'tomato4', 'OrangeRed2',
    'OrangeRed3', 'OrangeRed4', 'red2', 'red3', 'red4', 'DeepPink2', 'DeepPink3', 'DeepPink4',
    'HotPink1', 'HotPink2', 'HotPink3', 'HotPink4', 'pink1', 'pink2', 'pink3', 'pink4',
    'LightPink1', 'LightPink2', 'LightPink3', 'LightPink4', 'PaleVioletRed1',
    'PaleVioletRed2', 'PaleVioletRed3', 'PaleVioletRed4', 'maroon1', 'maroon2',
    'maroon3', 'maroon4', 'VioletRed1', 'VioletRed2', 'VioletRed3', 'VioletRed4',
    'magenta2', 'magenta3', 'magenta4', 'orchid1', 'orchid2', 'orchid3', 'orchid4', 'plum1',
    'plum2', 'plum3', 'plum4', 'MediumOrchid1', 'MediumOrchid2', 'MediumOrchid3',
    'MediumOrchid4', 'DarkOrchid1', 'DarkOrchid2', 'DarkOrchid3', 'DarkOrchid4',
    'purple1', 'purple2', 'purple3', 'purple4', 'MediumPurple1', 'MediumPurple2',
    'MediumPurple3', 'MediumPurple4', 'thistle1', 'thistle2', 'thistle3', 'thistle4',
    'gray1', 'gray2', 'gray3', 'gray4', 'gray5', 'gray6', 'gray7', 'gray8', 'gray9', 'gray10',
    'gray11', 'gray12', 'gray13', 'gray14', 'gray15', 'gray16', 'gray17', 'gray18', 'gray19',
    'gray20', 'gray21', 'gray22', 'gray23', 'gray24', 'gray25', 'gray26', 'gray27', 'gray28',
    'gray29', 'gray30', 'gray31', 'gray32', 'gray33', 'gray34', 'gray35', 'gray36', 'gray37',
    'gray38', 'gray39', 'gray40', 'gray42', 'gray43', 'gray44', 'gray45', 'gray46', 'gray47',
    'gray48', 'gray49', 'gray50', 'gray51', 'gray52', 'gray53', 'gray54', 'gray55', 'gray56',
    'gray57', 'gray58', 'gray59', 'gray60', 'gray61', 'gray62', 'gray63', 'gray64', 'gray65',
    'gray66', 'gray67', 'gray68', 'gray69', 'gray70', 'gray71', 'gray72', 'gray73', 'gray74',
    'gray75', 'gray76', 'gray77', 'gray78', 'gray79', 'gray80', 'gray81', 'gray82', 'gray83',
    'gray84', 'gray85', 'gray86', 'gray87', 'gray88', 'gray89', 'gray90', 'gray91', 'gray92',
    'gray93', 'gray94', 'gray95', 'gray97', 'gray98', 'gray99']

# The position and size relative to the screen
app.geometry('500x500+450+140')

# The title of the program
app.title('Maths4Primary')

# The icon
app.wm_iconbitmap('MathIcon.ico')

# Object positioning in the program
# def GridPos:

# I might use the place() method for the screen layout.
Label(app, text="Put these prices in order", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=100,y=10)

Label(app, text= u"\xA3" + "20.50", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=50,y=35)

Label(app, text=u"\xA3" + "2.50", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=200,y=35)

Label(app, text= u"\xA3" + "0.25", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=350,y=35)

# Entry
def get_data():
    x_data = x.get()
    y_data = y.get()
    z_data = z.get()
    print "x_data = {0} , y_data = {1} , z_data = {2}".format(x_data,y_data,z_data)

# I NEED HELP ON THIS PART 
if x == 0.25:
    print("Well done")

x = Entry(app)
y = Entry(app)
z = Entry(app)

x.place(x=50,y=60)
y.place(x=200,y=60)
z.place(x=350,y=60)

# Buttons
B1 = Button(app,text='Marks',bg='gold',fg='blue', command = messagePop ).place(x=425,y=450)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unless I'm completely confused you're just looking for "and"? I.e. "if x==0.25 and y==someYValue and z==someZValue"

Comment: Did you really need to post all that code for such a simple question?

Comment: I recommend against using `place`; if you are just now learning, learn the right thing. `pack` and `grid` are what you should normally be using. Using `place` makes it difficult to create a GUI that responds properly to resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code needs some rearrangement. It will not work in its current form.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

global x_data,y_data,z_data                       #----------add this

def get_data():
    global x_data,y_data,z_data
    x_data = x.get()
    y_data = y.get()
    z_data = z.get()
    print "x_data = {0} , y_data = {1} , z_data = {2}".format(x_data,y_data,z_data)

def messagePop():
    get_data()
    #---your Entry, which YOU NEED HELP ON THIS PART 
    if (x_data==0.25) and (y_data==2.5) and (z_data==20.5):   #----------compare here
        print("Well done")
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('Results', '100% Very Good')

#---your GUI design part----------------------------------------------
app = Tk()
app.configure(bg='cornflower blue')
COLORS = [...]
app.geometry('500x500+450+140')
app.title('Maths4Primary')
app.wm_iconbitmap('MathIcon.ico')
x = Entry(app)
y = Entry(app)
z = Entry(app)
x.place(x=50,y=60)
y.place(x=200,y=60)
z.place(x=350,y=60)
Label(app, text="Put these prices in order", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=100,y=10)
Label(app, text= u"\xA3" + "20.50", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=50,y=35)
Label(app, text=u"\xA3" + "2.50", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=200,y=35)
Label(app, text= u"\xA3" + "0.25", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=350,y=35)
B1 = Button(app,text='Marks',bg='gold',fg='blue', command = messagePop ).place(x=425,y=450)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh its a lot easier than I thought, thank you for the help :)